# Aptana 3.0.5 Problems View with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, aptana, jslint

I've recently looked into migrating off Coda and over to Aptana.  So I could get some realtime JavaScript/HTML/CSS error and warning notifications, as well as intellisense while programming.  I installed Aptana 3.0.5 and set up the Validation to include JSLint.
I notice warning icons next to line numbers, but no list of warnings or errors appear in the Problems view/panel and this puzzles me.

I'm running OS X Lion 10.7.1, and decide to test on my MacBook Pro.  Same thing occurs.
I locate a Snow Leopard 10.5.8 system and try it out, and the same thing occurs.

So now I'm wondering; Do errors and warnings in JavaScript even appear in the Problems View?  And if not, does this mean I just have to scroll up and down the file to locate errors this way?

Thanks

[EDIT: I went back to Aptana 2.0 and the Validation View seems to be working correctly.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you opening the file from a project in the workspace or directly from the local filesystem?  If the latter, this is currently the expected behavior, as Problems view only handles markers from workspace resources.

You could promote a local folder to become a project using [the instructions here](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Importing+an+Existing+Project#ImportinganExistingProject-UsingPromotetoProject), and then opening the JS file in the project will make the errors appear in the Problems view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Michael, That makes sense I'm going to give it a shot.  I was opening  just a local file to see how it would run.